# Testem returning "command not found" in terminal

Tags: terminal, bash, javascript

I am attempting to call testem on a directory in my terminal. It was working for a while, but now every time I call testem it returns the message "-bash: testem: command not found"

I must have done something to cause this, but I can't figure out what it is.

I have reinstalled testem a number of times, but it is not working. It is also not an issue of npm permissions.

How do I fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure enough for this to be an answer, but it's possible that this is a $PATH issue. You may have changed $PATH once, in your shell, to get this to work, but without putting that change in your shell startup files so the PATH is properly set for all your new Terminal windows.

Comment: What's the full command that you're running?